# how to extract two entities with conjunction in between those word using spacy python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

My Rule based matching code is like,

```
nlp = English()

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "XXX"}, {"ORTH": "("}, {"label": "ORG", "pattern": "XXXXX"}, {"ORTH": ")"}, 
           {"TEXT": "and"},
           {"label": "ORG", "pattern": "YY YY YY"}, {"ORTH": "("}, {"label": "ORG", "pattern": "YYY YYY YYY"},{"ORTH": ")"}]

matcher.add('organisation', None, pattern)

nlp.add_pipe(matcher)
```

My input will be like, This is between the XXXX(XXXX) and YY YY YY(YY YY YY).

I want output to be like XXXX(XXXX) and YY YY YY(YY YY YY).

I tried the above code but is not working for me. Is it possible to combine both Phrasematcher and Entity matcher in spacy python.

Comment: What are you trying to recognize? Can you give some examples?

Comment: I am trying to extract two entities with their relationship keyword. eg. INPUT SENTENCES: 1)X and Y are in agreement. i need output as X and Y. INPUT SENTENCES2). the agreement  is Y and Z. output: Y and Z

Comment: Sorry I don't see how your patterns should match `X`, `Y`, `Z`... I suggest providing real-world examples

Answer (score 0):

Try using rightID and LeftID instead of using "pattern" and check the dependencies between them:

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.matcher import DependencyMatcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
dep_matcher = DependencyMatcher(vocab=nlp.vocab)


#patterns
dep_pattern1 = [{'RIGHT_ID': 'word1', 'RIGHT_ATTRS': {'POS': 'PROPN','LABEL':'ORG'}},
               {'LEFT_ID': 'word2', 'REL_OP': '>', 'RIGHT_ID': 'word1', 'RIGHT_ATTRS': {'DEP': 'conj','POS':'PROPN','LABEL':'ORG'}
              ]
dep_matcher.add('conjjj', patterns=[dep_pattern_7])

doc = nlp('Apple and Samsumg are competitors')
dep_matches = dep_matcher(doc)

for match in dep_matches:
     pattern_name = nlp.vocab[match[0]].text
     matches = match[1]
     if pattern_name == 'conjjj':
          ogr1, org2 = matches[0], matches[1]
          print(org1 + " :  " + org2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).